# How to check linear combinations for independence

Tags: covariance, independence

If we have 2 newly defined normally distributed variables $U = 2X + 3Y$ and $V = X +3Z$, and the expectations and covariance structure of $[X,Y,Z]$, how can I check if $U$ and $V$ are independent?

I know that $\text{Cov}(U,V) = 0$ doesn't necessarily prove independence. Is there any other way i can check if these are independent?

Comment: I can't recall if there's a nifty counter-example, but I think under the assumptions of the above, two variables $U$, $V$ having a marginal normal distribution gives that 0 covariance is independence. Also linear combinations of normals are normal, so you can say $U,V$ are normal.

Comment: You cannot check independence by computing covariances unless you make specific assumptions about the joint distribution of $(X,Y,Z).$ The commonest one is that this distribution is multivariate Normal.  At "I know that" you suggest you are *not* in such a situation.  If there is some other method, then, it will have to rely on information you haven't disclosed to us.

Comment: Actually, I see now that it is mentioned the vector $ (X, Y, Z)^T $. Has multivariate distribution. But I still don't see how that helps.